# Google Function service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I'm trying to deploy a function to Google Function running as a different service account other than the default "PROJECT_ID"@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

Is this even possible?

What I've tried until now is:

1. Auth as the service account and run the deploy command
2. Auth as the service account and run the deploy command using "--account"

The functions keep getting deployed with the default serviceAccount.

Thanks

**EDIT (2019/02/13):**

As stated by @JJC, This is now available via gcloud beta features via:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy ... --service-account=$YOUR_SA_HERE
```

**EDIT (2023/07/06):**
As stated by @TinyTiger this is now GA: see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620416/2849525)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now available via gcloud beta features:

`gcloud beta functions deploy ... --service-account=$YOUR_SA_HERE`

Answer (score 4):

## **2023 UPDATE:**

It can be done like this:

`gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

**Read more [in the offical docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#adding_a_user-managed_service_account_at_deployment).**

Also note you can use `=` in-between if you want. Both styles work. For example, both of these will work...

With `=` works:

`gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

Without `=` also works:

`gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

Comment: Thanks @TinyTiger - I've updated the original Q linking to your response!

Answer (score 2):

### Update Oct 2018

This is available now via [gcloud alpha sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/functions/deploy#--service-account), i.e

`gcloud alpha functions deploy`
`--service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT`

> The email address of the IAM service account associated with the function at runtime. The service account represents the identity of the running function, and determines what permissions the function has.
>   If not provided, the function will use the project's default service account.

A note: 
It's probably necessary to [sign up for the alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdC5fVyYH7_L005FzPRzojgR4UgadpueyjSIgWpimwqxBy8Lg/viewform) in order to use. When I try it (not having signed up for alpha), it deploys without error, but seems to ignore the new flag and use the default service account.

The good news is that it is coming, hopefully it will hit beta soon.

For anyone that may be interested, here is a link to a great use case with example code -- basic solution to secure secrets in your cloud functions: 
[Secrets in Serverless | Seth Vargo](https://www.sethvargo.com/secrets-in-serverless/)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63801748

It's a feature that is still not available at the moment.

Comment: by any chance did you find solution to this as in this thread they never mentioned that they are working on this?

Comment: Actually, yeah they did mention that they are working on it, look at this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63801748#comment9

Comment: Yes, read it sorry what I wanted to say was that they never talked about any progress on it and still it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

And from the UI, you can choose the Service Account from here:

[image]